# How select value which will have a maximum occurrences in the table.?

Tags: mysql

Structure table test:

```
id(int)
name (varchar)
val (varchar)
```

Values:

```
1   test1  11
2   test2  22
3   test3  11
4   test4  22
5   test5  33
6   test6  33
7   test7  11
8   test8  22
9   test9  11
```

Me need select from table `test` one value `val` which will have a maximum occurrences in the table.

In my example maximum occurrences in the table will be have value `11`.

Tell me please how get it value(11) with `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT val FROM test
GROUP BY val
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dee81/1).